# SImple Pagination is not working in Laravel

Tags: laravel, pagination

I want to implement simple pagination method for my data but it is not working which i do not know what have i done wrong.

```
public function showFavorites()
{

    $myId = Auth::user()->id;

    $usersfavorite = collect(new User);
    $favoritedId    = Favoriteuser::where('favoritedbyid', Auth::user()->id)->latest()->lists('favoritedid')->toArray();

    if(count($favoritedId) > 0){
        $ids_ordered = implode(',', $favoritedId);

        $usersfavorite = User::with('usercity','profile')->whereIn('users.id', $favoritedId)
            ->leftJoin('deactivateaccount', 'users.id', '=', 'deactivateaccount.user_id')
            ->where('deactivateaccount.user_id', null)
            ->where('users.is_possible_scammer', 0)
            ->where('users.issuspended', 0)
            ->where('users.isusernameapproved', 1)
            // ->where('hasapprovedaboutme', 1)
            // ->where('hasapprovedlookingfor', 1)
            // ->where('hasapprovedtagline', 1)
            ->where(function($sub_query)
            {
                $sub_query->where('users.flag', 1)
                    ->orWhereIn('users.membershiptype', ['admin', 'premium', 'free-premium', 'diamond']);
            })
            ->whereNotIn('users.id', function($query) use ($myId)
            {
                $query->select('blockedid')
                        ->from(with(new Blockeduser)->getTable())
                        ->where('blockedbyid', $myId);
            })
            ->whereNotIn('users.id', function($query) use ($myId)
            {
                $query->select('blockedbyid')
                        ->from(with(new Blockeduser)->getTable())
                        ->where('blockedid', $myId);
            })
            ->orderByRaw(DB::raw("FIELD(users.id, $ids_ordered)"))
            // ->take(self::INTEREST_RESULT_LIMIT_COUNT)
            ->select('*','users.id as id')
            ->simplePaginate(30);

            $livestream_metadata = $usersfavorite->map(function ($user)
            {
                $user['livestream_metadata'] = findLiveStreamingMetadata($user);

                return $user;
            });
    }
    dd($usersfavorite->previousPageUrl());
    $favorited = new Favoriteuser();

    return view('interests.favorites')
        ->with(['users' => $usersfavorite, 'favorited' => $favorited]);
}
```

When i dd($usersfavorite->previousPageUrl()); it has error saying that previousPageUrl Method is does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Run

```
dd(get_class($usersfavorite));
```

Which a class will you get? The method `previousPageUrl` is containing only in a `Paginator` class.

If condition `count($favoritedId) > 0` is false then `$usersfavorite` variable will be instance of `\Illuminate\Support\Collection` class.

The `\Illuminate\Support\Collection` class doesn't have `previousPageUrl` method. See [Laravel API](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html)

Answer (score 0):

When you call `map` on the `$usersfavorite`, it returns a collection which does not contain the `previousPageUrl` method.
What you want is to use the `tap` helper method before you `map`. This returns the `Paginator` object you had before you `map`ped.

```
...
$livestream_metadata = tap($usersfavorite)->map(function ($user) {
        $user['livestream_metadata'] = findLiveStreamingMetadata($user);

        return $user;
    });
...
```